# Is it possible to develop Windows Phone 7 apps using Adobe Air?

Tags: windows-phone-7, air

I have spent a great deal of time researching if this is a possibility but I can't find any evidence of using AIR to develop windows phone 7 apps nor any information regarding future support.

I am interested in finding out once and for all, if it's possible for me to compile my Adobe AIR application into a native Windows Phone 7 app. If not, is there any press releases or information regarding the intended date for when this will become possible, if ever?

Comment: AIR apps don't run in browser, that's what they were created for.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Developing apps for Windows Phone with Adobe Air is not possible and there has been no announcement of any plans to add support.

As Adobe have dropped (are dropping?) support for mobile flash and seem to be pushing the HTML route for mobile development I think it would be very unlikely that AA support will ever made available for WP.

Comment: Adobe will continue support (security updates, etc) for their current versions of their mobile flash in browsers but will no longer commit new versions.  AIR, on the other hand, has and will continue to push the AVM2 runtime (Flash Player) into the future - particularly for mobile devices.

Comment: Please be careful when making statements mixing mobile Flash Player and the Adobe AIR platform. Adobe is NOT dropping Adobe AIR, applications developed in Flash are still able to run as native apps on iOS and Android phones. There is also a chance, albeit nothing official or confirmed, that Adobe will support Windows Phone in Adobe AIR. It would make a lot of sense, strategically speaking, to support another growing platform.

Comment: This answer mistakes [AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) for [Flash Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player).

Comment: @Saul I do not confuse the two, I simply make an assumption about one based on the situation regarding the other.

Comment: @MattLacey - AIR internally uses Adobe Flash Player as the runtime environment but this answer claims that "Adobe have dropped (are dropping?) support for mobile flash". You can't have mobile AIR without mobile Flash Player. At the moment only **mobile browser plugins** are being dropped, not AIR, which is under active and continuing development.

Answer (score 4):

Adobe is probably waiting for Windows phone to become more popular as a platform before they spend time getting AIR up and running on it. The mobile version of Flash player was discontinued primarily due to Apple blocking it. With half of the phone market unable to view Flash player content on mobile it didn't make a lot of sense for them to continue to invest in it when they have other things going on like AIR and some of the HTML work, not to mention all of their other products.

Comment: To be exact, Adobe discontinued **mobile browser plugins**, not mobile Flash Player which is [still being used in AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime).

Answer (score 2):

adobe is even more focusing on mobile development using adobe AIR (actionscript or html). Most of the mobile development is going on with AIR because of one code and many platforms feature. AIR is already supported by most widely used mobile platforms like andriod, iOS, blackberry.  I think microsoft will not want adobe AIR technology penetrating into windows platforms as it will be the greatest set back to their own development toolkits and community. In one way or other, its also costing microsoft as apps which are available for iOS / andriod / BB are not available for windows, so ultimately microsoft will have to go to adobe for their support.

Answer (score 1):

Presently no but if Windows Phone market share grows large enough it is likely to become possible. At least the official [Adobe roadmap for the Flash runtimes](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html) shows no intention of pulling AIR back from the mobile landscape:

> Adobe continues to actively invest in enabling developers to create
>   and deploy Flash based content as mobile (and desktop) applications
>   via Adobe AIR.
>
> / ... /
>
> Adobe is committed to adding both Windows 8 Desktop and Metro as
>   supported platforms for Adobe AIR. We will update this document once
>   we have more specific information available.

Comment: desktop = windows 7 (desktop) style...
Metro != windows phone! ... -> Windows 8 Metro App Look (not Phone)

Comment: @Raegtime - True, thanks for pointing it out. However the roadmap does not exclude Windows Phone (version 8 is [nearly identical to Windows 8](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/featured/Windows-Phone-8-and-Windows-8-app-development)) and its chances of getting AIR support increase at the same pace as its [market share](http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/windows-phone-market-share-almost-triples-in-year). It goes without saying that Adobe has an incentive only if the market share justifies itself but whether that happens or not remains to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe released this document: '*Adobe roadmap for the Flash runtimes*', http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html   on February 2014 containing this statement (my italics):

> Adobe AIR is available and supported for Windows 8 Desktop on x86-based computers. *Adobe currently has no plans to support Adobe AIR for Windows 8 Modern UI applications or Windows Mobile.*
>
> Adobe and Microsoft are working closely together, and are investing in continuing to deliver Flash Player for Windows 8 and future versions of Windows on both Windows desktop and Modern UI.

See also this feature request: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3648920